# Use curve fitting to approximate a group of many straight line segments in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, regression, shapely

Suppose you have a group of connected line segments like in the picture below. How can you find a curve to approximate the collection of line segments as shown in the image on the right?

[image: Connected line segments number 1]
[image: Fitted line segments number 1]

This is similar to another question ([Approximate a group of line segments as a single best fit straight line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368615/approximate-a-group-of-line-segments-as-a-single-best-fit-straight-line)) with a couple of key differences.

1. There are many more lines, some of which are perpendicular to the line of best fit.
2. I am looking for a ***CURVE***, not just a line. This is important because I have other examples that cannot be approximated by a straight line. See below for one such example.
3. This is different from other questions about regression because I am asking specifically about how to fit a curve to lines instead of points. Also, I don't think that the solution is linear regression in this situation.

[image: Connected line segments number 2]

##### Sample Data

This is the data used to create the examples in the pictures. Pass these ndarrays to the `LineCollection(...)` function from matplotlib to replicate the plots.

```
data1 = np.array([[[553, 420], [553, 422]],[[553, 420], [554, 419]],[[553, 420], [555, 419]],[[553, 420], [554, 421]],[[553, 420], [555, 421]],[[553, 420], [554, 422]],[[553, 422], [554, 421]],[[553, 422], [555, 421]],[[553, 422], [554, 422]],[[557, 413], [558, 412]],[[558, 412], [558, 414]],[[557, 413], [558, 414]],[[556, 415], [557, 413]],[[557, 413], [557, 415]],[[556, 415], [558, 414]],[[557, 415], [558, 414]],[[556, 415], [557, 415]],[[556, 416], [558, 414]],[[557, 416], [558, 414]],[[556, 415], [556, 416]],[[556, 415], [557, 416]],[[555, 417], [556, 415]],[[556, 415], [557, 417]],[[556, 416], [557, 415]],[[557, 415], [557, 416]],[[555, 417], [557, 415]],[[557, 415], [557, 417]],[[556, 416], [557, 416]],[[555, 417], [556, 416]],[[556, 416], [557, 417]],[[556, 416], [556, 418]],[[555, 417], [557, 416]],[[557, 416], [557, 417]],[[556, 418], [557, 416]],[[555, 417], [557, 417]],[[555, 417], [556, 418]],[[554, 419], [555, 417]],[[555, 417], [555, 419]],[[556, 418], [557, 417]],[[555, 419], [557, 417]],[[554, 419], [556, 418]],[[555, 419], [556, 418]],[[554, 419], [555, 419]],[[554, 419], [554, 421]],[[554, 419], [555, 421]],[[554, 421], [555, 419]],[[555, 419], [555, 421]],[[554, 421], [555, 421]],[[554, 421], [554, 422]],[[554, 422], [555, 421]],[[558, 412], [559, 411]],[[558, 412], [559, 412]],[[558, 412], [560, 410]],[[557, 413], [559, 411]],[[557, 413], [559, 412]],[[558, 414], [559, 412]],[[559, 409], [559, 411]],[[559, 409], [560, 408]],[[559, 409], [560, 410]],[[559, 409], [561, 407]],[[559, 409], [561, 408]],[[559, 411], [559, 412]],[[559, 411], [560, 410]],[[559, 412], [560, 410]],[[560, 408], [560, 410]],[[560, 408], [561, 407]],[[560, 408], [561, 408]],[[560, 408], [562, 406]],[[560, 410], [561, 408]],[[561, 407], [561, 408]],[[561, 407], [562, 406]],[[561, 408], [562, 406]],[[553, 422], [553, 423]],[[552, 423], [553, 422]],[[553, 423], [554, 421]],[[552, 423], [554, 421]],[[553, 423], [555, 421]],[[553, 423], [554, 422]],[[552, 423], [554, 422]],[[552, 423], [553, 423]],[[552, 425], [553, 423]],[[551, 425], [553, 423]],[[553, 423], [553, 425]],[[552, 423], [552, 425]],[[551, 425], [552, 423]],[[552, 423], [553, 425]],[[551, 425], [552, 425]],[[552, 425], [553, 425]],[[551, 426], [552, 425]],[[552, 425], [552, 426]],[[551, 425], [553, 425]],[[551, 425], [551, 426]],[[551, 425], [552, 426]],[[551, 426], [553, 425]],[[552, 426], [553, 425]],[[551, 426], [552, 426]],[[551, 426], [551, 428]],[[550, 428], [551, 426]],[[551, 428], [552, 426]],[[550, 428], [552, 426]],[[550, 428], [551, 428]],[[550, 429], [551, 428]],[[550, 430], [551, 428]],[[550, 428], [550, 429]],[[550, 428], [550, 430]],[[550, 429], [550, 430]],[[549, 431], [550, 429]],[[550, 429], [550, 431]],[[549, 431], [550, 430]],[[550, 430], [550, 431]],[[548, 432], [550, 430]],[[549, 431], [550, 431]],[[548, 432], [549, 431]],[[549, 431], [549, 433]],[[548, 432], [550, 431]],[[549, 433], [550, 431]],[[548, 432], [549, 433]],[[548, 432], [549, 434]],[[548, 432], [548, 434]],[[549, 433], [549, 434]],[[548, 434], [549, 433]],[[547, 435], [549, 433]],[[548, 434], [549, 434]],[[547, 435], [549, 434]],[[548, 436], [549, 434]],[[547, 435], [548, 434]],[[548, 434], [548, 436]],[[547, 435], [548, 436]],[[547, 435], [547, 437]],[[547, 437], [548, 436]]], dtype=np.int64)
```

```
data2 = np.array([[[1142, 1698], [1142, 1699]],[[1142, 1698], [1144, 1699]],[[1142, 1698], [1144, 1700]],[[1142, 1699], [1144, 1699]],[[1142, 1699], [1144, 1700]],[[1144, 1699], [1144, 1700]],[[1144, 1699], [1145, 1698]],[[1144, 1699], [1146, 1699]],[[1144, 1699], [1146, 1700]],[[1144, 1700], [1145, 1698]],[[1144, 1700], [1146, 1699]],[[1144, 1700], [1146, 1700]],[[1145, 1698], [1146, 1699]],[[1145, 1698], [1146, 1700]],[[1146, 1699], [1146, 1700]],[[1146, 1699], [1148, 1700]],[[1146, 1700], [1148, 1700]],[[1144, 1699], [1145, 1701]],[[1144, 1699], [1146, 1701]],[[1144, 1700], [1145, 1701]],[[1144, 1700], [1146, 1701]],[[1145, 1701], [1146, 1699]],[[1146, 1699], [1146, 1701]],[[1146, 1699], [1148, 1701]],[[1145, 1701], [1146, 1700]],[[1146, 1700], [1146, 1701]],[[1146, 1700], [1148, 1701]],[[1146, 1700], [1147, 1702]],[[1146, 1701], [1148, 1700]],[[1148, 1700], [1148, 1701]],[[1147, 1702], [1148, 1700]],[[1148, 1700], [1150, 1702]],[[1145, 1701], [1146, 1701]],[[1145, 1701], [1147, 1702]],[[1145, 1701], [1146, 1703]],[[1146, 1701], [1148, 1701]],[[1146, 1701], [1147, 1702]],[[1146, 1701], [1146, 1703]],[[1147, 1702], [1148, 1701]],[[1148, 1701], [1150, 1702]],[[1146, 1703], [1148, 1701]],[[1148, 1701], [1149, 1703]],[[1146, 1703], [1147, 1702]],[[1147, 1702], [1149, 1703]],[[1149, 1703], [1150, 1702]],[[1147, 1702], [1148, 1704]],[[1148, 1704], [1150, 1702]],[[1150, 1702], [1151, 1704]],[[1146, 1703], [1148, 1704]],[[1148, 1704], [1149, 1703]],[[1149, 1703], [1151, 1704]],[[1149, 1703], [1150, 1705]],[[1148, 1704], [1150, 1705]],[[1150, 1705], [1151, 1704]],[[1151, 1704], [1151, 1706]],[[1151, 1704], [1152, 1706]],[[1150, 1705], [1151, 1706]],[[1150, 1705], [1152, 1706]],[[1150, 1705], [1151, 1707]],[[1151, 1706], [1152, 1706]],[[1151, 1706], [1151, 1707]],[[1151, 1706], [1152, 1708]],[[1151, 1706], [1151, 1708]],[[1151, 1707], [1152, 1706]],[[1152, 1706], [1152, 1708]],[[1151, 1708], [1152, 1706]],[[1151, 1707], [1152, 1708]],[[1151, 1707], [1151, 1708]],[[1151, 1707], [1152, 1709]],[[1151, 1708], [1152, 1708]],[[1152, 1708], [1152, 1709]],[[1151, 1710], [1152, 1708]],[[1151, 1708], [1152, 1709]],[[1151, 1708], [1151, 1710]],[[1151, 1710], [1152, 1709]],[[1151, 1710], [1152, 1712]],[[1152, 1718], [1152, 1719]],[[1152, 1718], [1152, 1720]],[[1152, 1719], [1152, 1720]],[[1152, 1719], [1152, 1721]],[[1152, 1720], [1152, 1721]],[[1151, 1722], [1152, 1720]],[[1152, 1720], [1152, 1722]],[[1151, 1722], [1152, 1721]],[[1152, 1721], [1152, 1722]],[[1151, 1723], [1152, 1721]],[[1151, 1722], [1152, 1722]],[[1151, 1722], [1151, 1723]],[[1151, 1723], [1152, 1722]],[[1151, 1722], [1152, 1724]],[[1150, 1724], [1151, 1722]],[[1152, 1722], [1152, 1724]],[[1150, 1724], [1152, 1722]],[[1151, 1723], [1152, 1724]],[[1150, 1724], [1151, 1723]],[[1151, 1723], [1151, 1725]],[[1150, 1724], [1152, 1724]],[[1151, 1725], [1152, 1724]],[[1150, 1726], [1152, 1724]],[[1151, 1726], [1152, 1724]],[[1150, 1724], [1151, 1725]],[[1150, 1724], [1150, 1726]],[[1150, 1724], [1151, 1726]],[[1150, 1726], [1151, 1725]],[[1151, 1725], [1151, 1726]],[[1149, 1727], [1151, 1725]],[[1150, 1727], [1151, 1725]],[[1150, 1726], [1151, 1726]],[[1149, 1727], [1150, 1726]],[[1150, 1726], [1150, 1727]],[[1149, 1728], [1150, 1726]],[[1149, 1727], [1151, 1726]],[[1150, 1727], [1151, 1726]],[[1149, 1728], [1151, 1726]],[[1149, 1727], [1150, 1727]],[[1147, 1728], [1149, 1727]],[[1149, 1727], [1149, 1728]],[[1149, 1728], [1150, 1727]],[[1147, 1728], [1149, 1728]],[[1151, 1704], [1153, 1704]],[[1151, 1706], [1153, 1704]],[[1151, 1706], [1153, 1707]],[[1151, 1706], [1153, 1708]],[[1152, 1706], [1153, 1704]],[[1152, 1706], [1153, 1707]],[[1152, 1706], [1153, 1708]],[[1151, 1707], [1153, 1707]],[[1151, 1707], [1153, 1708]],[[1152, 1708], [1153, 1707]],[[1152, 1708], [1153, 1708]],[[1152, 1708], [1154, 1709]],[[1152, 1708], [1154, 1710]],[[1151, 1708], [1153, 1707]],[[1151, 1708], [1153, 1708]],[[1152, 1709], [1153, 1707]],[[1152, 1709], [1153, 1708]],[[1152, 1709], [1154, 1709]],[[1152, 1709], [1154, 1710]],[[1152, 1709], [1153, 1711]],[[1151, 1710], [1153, 1708]],[[1151, 1710], [1153, 1711]],[[1152, 1712], [1154, 1710]],[[1152, 1712], [1153, 1711]],[[1152, 1712], [1154, 1712]],[[1152, 1712], [1153, 1713]],[[1152, 1712], [1154, 1713]],[[1152, 1712], [1153, 1714]],[[1152, 1718], [1153, 1716]],[[1152, 1718], [1154, 1716]],[[1152, 1718], [1153, 1717]],[[1152, 1718], [1154, 1718]],[[1152, 1719], [1153, 1717]],[[1152, 1719], [1154, 1718]],[[1152, 1720], [1154, 1718]],[[1152, 1718], [1153, 1719]],[[1152, 1718], [1154, 1719]],[[1152, 1718], [1153, 1720]],[[1152, 1719], [1153, 1719]],[[1152, 1719], [1154, 1719]],[[1152, 1719], [1153, 1720]],[[1152, 1719], [1154, 1721]],[[1152, 1720], [1153, 1719]],[[1152, 1720], [1154, 1719]],[[1152, 1720], [1153, 1720]],[[1152, 1720], [1154, 1721]],[[1152, 1720], [1153, 1722]],[[1152, 1720], [1154, 1722]],[[1152, 1721], [1153, 1719]],[[1152, 1721], [1154, 1719]],[[1152, 1721], [1153, 1720]],[[1152, 1721], [1154, 1721]],[[1152, 1721], [1153, 1722]],[[1152, 1721], [1154, 1722]],[[1152, 1721], [1153, 1723]],[[1151, 1722], [1153, 1720]],[[1151, 1722], [1153, 1722]],[[1151, 1722], [1153, 1723]],[[1152, 1722], [1153, 1720]],[[1152, 1722], [1154, 1721]],[[1152, 1722], [1153, 1722]],[[1152, 1722], [1154, 1722]],[[1152, 1722], [1153, 1723]],[[1151, 1723], [1153, 1722]],[[1151, 1723], [1153, 1723]],[[1152, 1724], [1153, 1722]],[[1152, 1724], [1154, 1722]],[[1152, 1724], [1153, 1723]],[[1151, 1725], [1153, 1723]],[[1153, 1707], [1153, 1708]],[[1153, 1707], [1154, 1709]],[[1153, 1708], [1154, 1709]],[[1153, 1708], [1154, 1710]],[[1154, 1709], [1154, 1710]],[[1153, 1711], [1154, 1709]],[[1154, 1709], [1155, 1711]],[[1153, 1711], [1154, 1710]],[[1154, 1710], [1155, 1711]],[[1153, 1711], [1155, 1711]],[[1154, 1710], [1154, 1712]],[[1153, 1711], [1154, 1712]],[[1153, 1711], [1153, 1713]],[[1153, 1711], [1154, 1713]],[[1154, 1712], [1155, 1711]],[[1153, 1713], [1155, 1711]],[[1154, 1713], [1155, 1711]],[[1155, 1711], [1156, 1713]],[[1153, 1713], [1154, 1712]],[[1154, 1712], [1154, 1713]],[[1154, 1712], [1156, 1713]],[[1153, 1714], [1154, 1712]],[[1154, 1712], [1155, 1714]],[[1153, 1713], [1154, 1713]],[[1153, 1713], [1153, 1714]],[[1153, 1713], [1155, 1714]],[[1153, 1713], [1155, 1715]],[[1153, 1713], [1154, 1715]],[[1154, 1713], [1156, 1713]],[[1153, 1714], [1154, 1713]],[[1154, 1713], [1155, 1714]],[[1154, 1713], [1155, 1715]],[[1154, 1713], [1154, 1715]],[[1155, 1714], [1156, 1713]],[[1155, 1715], [1156, 1713]],[[1154, 1715], [1156, 1713]],[[1153, 1714], [1155, 1714]],[[1153, 1714], [1155, 1715]],[[1153, 1714], [1154, 1715]],[[1155, 1714], [1155, 1715]],[[1154, 1715], [1155, 1714]],[[1154, 1715], [1155, 1715]],[[1153, 1714], [1153, 1716]],[[1153, 1714], [1154, 1716]],[[1153, 1716], [1155, 1714]],[[1154, 1716], [1155, 1714]],[[1153, 1716], [1155, 1715]],[[1154, 1716], [1155, 1715]],[[1153, 1717], [1155, 1715]],[[1153, 1716], [1154, 1715]],[[1154, 1715], [1154, 1716]],[[1153, 1717], [1154, 1715]],[[1153, 1714], [1155, 1716]],[[1155, 1714], [1155, 1716]],[[1155, 1714], [1156, 1716]],[[1155, 1715], [1155, 1716]],[[1155, 1715], [1155, 1717]],[[1155, 1715], [1156, 1716]],[[1154, 1715], [1155, 1716]],[[1154, 1715], [1155, 1717]],[[1154, 1715], [1156, 1716]],[[1153, 1716], [1154, 1716]],[[1153, 1716], [1153, 1717]],[[1153, 1716], [1154, 1718]],[[1153, 1717], [1154, 1716]],[[1154, 1716], [1154, 1718]],[[1153, 1717], [1154, 1718]],[[1153, 1717], [1153, 1719]],[[1153, 1717], [1154, 1719]],[[1153, 1719], [1154, 1718]],[[1154, 1718], [1154, 1719]],[[1153, 1720], [1154, 1718]],[[1153, 1719], [1154, 1719]],[[1153, 1719], [1153, 1720]],[[1153, 1719], [1154, 1721]],[[1153, 1720], [1154, 1719]],[[1154, 1719], [1154, 1721]],[[1153, 1720], [1154, 1721]],[[1153, 1720], [1153, 1722]],[[1153, 1720], [1154, 1722]],[[1153, 1722], [1154, 1721]],[[1154, 1721], [1154, 1722]],[[1153, 1723], [1154, 1721]],[[1153, 1722], [1154, 1722]],[[1153, 1722], [1153, 1723]],[[1153, 1723], [1154, 1722]],[[1153, 1716], [1155, 1716]],[[1153, 1716], [1155, 1717]],[[1153, 1716], [1155, 1718]],[[1154, 1716], [1155, 1716]],[[1154, 1716], [1155, 1717]],[[1154, 1716], [1155, 1718]],[[1154, 1716], [1156, 1716]],[[1154, 1716], [1156, 1718]],[[1153, 1717], [1155, 1716]],[[1153, 1717], [1155, 1717]],[[1153, 1717], [1155, 1718]],[[1154, 1718], [1155, 1716]],[[1154, 1718], [1155, 1717]],[[1154, 1718], [1155, 1718]],[[1154, 1718], [1156, 1716]],[[1154, 1718], [1156, 1718]],[[1153, 1719], [1155, 1717]],[[1153, 1719], [1155, 1718]],[[1154, 1719], [1155, 1717]],[[1154, 1719], [1155, 1718]],[[1154, 1719], [1156, 1718]],[[1153, 1720], [1155, 1718]],[[1155, 1716], [1155, 1717]],[[1155, 1716], [1155, 1718]],[[1155, 1716], [1156, 1716]],[[1155, 1716], [1156, 1718]],[[1155, 1717], [1155, 1718]],[[1155, 1717], [1156, 1716]],[[1155, 1717], [1156, 1718]],[[1155, 1718], [1156, 1716]],[[1155, 1718], [1156, 1718]],[[1156, 1716], [1156, 1718]],[[1148, 1729], [1149, 1727]],[[1148, 1729], [1150, 1727]],[[1147, 1728], [1148, 1729]],[[1148, 1729], [1149, 1728]]], dtype=np.int64)
```

##### What I have tried

The answer to the question linked above helped me write the following code. Essentially, it finds the vertices of the convex hull around the collection of line segments. Then, using these vertices, the code performs linear regression to find the line of best fit. Finally, the line is cropped so that it is entirely contained by the convex hull polygon. Of course this does not work for non-linear line segment collections. Any suggestions would be welcome!

[image: Convex hull around line collection]
[image: Line of best fit extended]
[image: Line of best fit cropped]

##### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection, LineCollection
from scipy.stats import linregress
from scipy.spatial import KDTree, ConvexHull
from shapely import box, LineString, normalize, Polygon, polygons, intersection

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,11))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

pairs = np.reshape(np.array(data1), (data1.shape[0]*2,2))
hull = ConvexHull(pairs)

line_coll = LineCollection(data1, linewidth=1.0, colors='r')
ax.add_collection(line_coll)
for simp in hull.simplices:
    ax.plot(pairs[simp,0], pairs[simp,1], c='w')

lreg = linregress(pairs)
xs = [0, (-1 *(lreg.intercept /lreg.slope))]
ys = [lreg.intercept, 0]
lstr = LineString([(xs[0],ys[0]), (xs[1],ys[1])])
plyg = polygons(pairs[hull.vertices])
coords = intersection(lstr, plyg).xy

ax.plot(coords[0], coords[1], linewidth=2.5, c='b')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can not just consider all the points and fit a curve over those points? What is the significance of them being line segments?

Comment: If you have curves for which you can define a normal distance (for example, a circular arc would probably fit your example picture, with radius and centre coordinates to be found) then you can minimise the sum of the squared distances from that curve.